# How do desktop environments get login details and process them?

Tags: linux, login

Well how do desktop environments like lightdm get login details via a GUI? How do they convert those details to terminal?

Comment: the question is not clear enough. what do you mean by `convert those details to terminal`

Comment: Well basically how does it login via gui if we are using a terminal then it shows user:   password:         so I thought desktop manager was a gui written to interface that terminal login